# Download resource with HTTP caching

Tags: http, haskell, caching, server

To validate `jwt` tokens at server I'm using `jwk` ([Google](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs)) certs (changing frequently) and, even exist many libraries to download that ([HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.20), [curl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl), [http-conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.8), ...), I can't found the way to set some local/global/memory/per-thread/... HTTP cache.

My current ugly but feasible alternatives are:

1. read `Cache-Control` and/or `Expires` headers and perform my own ugly HTTP caching.
2. configure one (out of the box server) proxy.

How do you deal with HTTP caching at server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 here

```
httpManager   <- newManager someManagerSettings
mySimpleCache <- makeSimpleHttpCache httpManager responseToMyCachedData
....
a <- mySimpleCache urlA
....
```

e.g. caching response body length

```
> c <- makeSimpleHttpCache m (\r -> putStrLn "Downloaded!" >> return $ C8.length $ responseBody r)
> c "https://some-url-with-small-cache-control"
Downloaded!
Right 21108
> c "https://some-url-with-small-cache-control"
Right 21108
> c "https://some-url-with-small-cache-control"
Right 21108
> c "https://some-url-with-small-cache-control"
Downloaded!
Right 21108
> c "https://some-url-with-small-cache-control"
Right 21108
>
```

code

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Network.HTTP.Client.Cached where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Network.Connection
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Time.Format
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import Control.Arrow hiding ((+++))
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Catch
import Data.Maybe
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Data.Char

type Res = Response L.ByteString

makeSimpleHttpCache :: (MonadCatch m, MonadIO m) => Manager -> (Res -> m a) -> m (String -> m (Either String a))
makeSimpleHttpCache manager onLoad = do
    cacheRef <- liftIO $ newMVar M.empty
    return $ \url -> do
        cache <- liftIO $ takeMVar cacheRef
        (cache', a) <- flip catchAll (\e -> return (cache, Left $ show e)) $ do
                            t <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
                            case (second (>t) <$> M.lookup url cache) of
                                Just (y, True) -> return (cache, Right y)
                                _ -> do
                                       u <- liftIO $ parseUrlThrow url
                                       r <- liftIO (httpLbs u manager)
                                       a <- onLoad r
                                       case computeExpireTime t r of
                                           Just t' -> return (M.insertWith const url (a, t') cache, Right a)
                                           _       -> return (cache, Right a)
        liftIO $ putMVar cacheRef cache'
        return a

computeExpireTime :: POSIXTime -> Res -> Maybe POSIXTime
computeExpireTime now rs =
    let hs              = responseHeaders rs
        expires         = do    e <- lookupHeader hExpires hs
                                t <- parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%a, %e %b %Y %T %Z" (C8.unpack e)
                                return $ utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds t
        cachecontrol    = do    c <- lookupHeader hCacheControl hs
                                d <- readMaxAge $ C8.unpack c
                                return $ now + fromIntegral d
    in  cachecontrol <|> expires

readMaxAge :: String -> Maybe Int
readMaxAge = fmap fst . listToMaybe . readP_to_S p
    where p = (string "max-age=" >> read <$> munch isDigit) +++ (get >>= const p)

lookupHeader :: HeaderName -> [Header] -> Maybe C8.ByteString
lookupHeader h = listToMaybe . map snd . filter ((h==) . fst)

hExpires :: HeaderName
hExpires = "Expires"
```

Comment: Warning for production use: this implementation doesn't handle failing URLs.